# Как решить проблему с черным экраном vlc player в ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, vlc

Звук проигрывается а вот видео нет.
Не совсем понимаю, как решить эту задачу.

Comment: Без диагностики - никак, а ее тут нет.

Comment: А mpv\smplayer работают или тоже видео нет?

Answer (score 0):

Не кодеки, а в настройках вывод установить x11. 
Но все равно спасибо, что откликнулись.